# specifying nuget package sources

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, build-server

My build server fails to build because the package source cannot be found. Here's how I want to specify it:

```
 <PackageSources><add key="My Feed" value="http://tfs2010:90/CompName.Nuget.Web.$(Configuration)/Nuget" /></PackageSources>
```

The error:

C:\TFS2010\TFS\Nuget\nuget.Other.targets (43): The command ""C:\tmp\nuget.exe" install "C:\Builds\1\PC\PackNameSources\PackName\packages.config" -source  -o "C:\Builds\1\PC\PackName\Sources\packages"" exited with code -1.

Now, of course if I do that:

```
<PackageSources>"http://tfs2010:90/MyFeed/Nuget"</PackageSources>
```

then it works fine.

The problem is that eventually, I want to specify multiple sources.

How can I do that and what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

the solution was to separate the sources with a semi-colon :

```
<PackageSources>"source1; source2"</PackageSources>
```